# Identify certain Day from a xts-Matrix R

Tags: r, matrix, xts, days

`kperf_dfa` is my matrix with five different performances over the last month. It looks like this:

```
> kperf_dfa[150:160,]
                            [,1]         [,2]         [,3]          [,4]          [,5]
2016-01-29 17:45:00 0.0003693252 0.0003693252 0.0003693252 -7.952367e-05 -7.952367e-05
2016-01-29 17:50:00 0.0003693252 0.0003693252 0.0003693252 -7.952367e-05 -7.952367e-05
2016-01-29 17:55:00 0.0003693252 0.0003693252 0.0003693252 -7.952367e-05 -7.952367e-05
2016-01-29 18:00:00 0.0004134665 0.0004134665 0.0004134665 -3.538234e-05 -3.538234e-05
2016-01-29 18:05:00 0.0004134665 0.0004134665 0.0004134665 -3.538234e-05 -3.538234e-05
2016-01-29 18:10:00 0.0004134665 0.0004134665 0.0004134665 -3.538234e-05 -3.538234e-05
2016-01-29 18:15:00 0.0004134665 0.0004134665 0.0004134665 -3.538234e-05 -3.538234e-05
2016-01-29 18:20:00 0.0004134665 0.0004134665 0.0004134665 -3.538234e-05 -3.538234e-05
2016-01-29 18:25:00 0.0004134665 0.0004134665 0.0004134665 -3.538234e-05 -3.538234e-05
2016-01-29 18:30:00 0.0004134665 0.0004134665 0.0004134665 -3.538234e-05 -3.538234e-05
2016-01-29 18:35:00 0.0004134665 0.0004134665 0.0004134665 -3.538234e-05 -3.538234e-05
```

I already know how to identify the weekdays. With:

```
as.matrix(kperf_dfa[.indexwday(kperf_dfa) == 5])
```

for example I can get all Fridays.

Now I want to go get just the 2nd of all Fridays.
Any ideas how to get this? Thank you guys.

Comment: the second of all Fridays? For the entire data set or second Friday of a month?

Comment: It would be the second Friday of the entire data set. @user3507767

Answer (score 0):

I would try a logical test with both _wday and _mday clauses:

```
as.matrix(kperf_dfa[.indexwday(kperf_dfa) == 5 & .indexmday %in% 8:14])
```